# Development on an Ubuntu tablet

Tags: programming, tablet

For college, I program now and then in C, C++, C#, JAVA, Lisp, python, Sql, ...

Will it be possible to do development in Ubuntu tablet environment in the same I can on Ubuntu desktop?"

Answer (score 0):

A tablet is not really an option to do any serious programming with. If you mean whether you can develop FOR tablet, well of course you can. Check out [Ubuntu Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/) website.

Comment: See the re-edited question. I think the OP is interested in more casual, short class assignment style programs and is wondering if he will be able to run/install compilers, IDE's, etc in Touch.